# Kак правильно сказать: гид по Москве или гид в Москве?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Kак правильно сказать: гид по Москве или гид в Москве?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны в зависимости от контекста. **Гид по Москве** водит туристов по Москве, а **гид в Москве** живет/находится/работает в Москве.

Answer (score 0):

**ГИД**, 1. Человек, сопровождающий туристов и показывающий им достопримечательности города, местности и т.п

Мы говорим "гид по Москве", при этом имеем в виду, что это его специализация.

Можно сказать "гид в Москве", но это выражение встретишь не часто.

**Примеры с предлогом В:**

Не люблю я американцев, ― сказал мне один гид в Норвегии. [Виктор Розов. (1960-2000)]

Можно также сказать: гид в музее, в автобусе, в той поездке.

Answer (score -1):

Я согласен с  авторами предыдущих комментариев. Гид в Москве - живет, работает, а по Москве -  проводит экскурсии, специализируется, третье трудно придумать.

Comment: Предыдущие комментарии — ответы. И если нет иного мотива, как только согласиться с ними, почему не написать к ним комментарий?